# How do I add a transition effect to slowly load my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page loads directly which is very fast, I basically want to load my page after some transition-duration. Once the transition fades away, the webpage should slowly load/appear.

I've been trying to figure this out for a long time but I don't know how to add a transition effect in Javascript.

```js
<script>
var overlay = document.getElementById("loading");
window.addEventListener('load',function()
{
overlay.style.display = 'none';
})
</script>
 follwoing is css file
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

#loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.loading-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 100px;
 
}
.loading-text span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
 
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
            filter: blur(4px);
  }
}

@keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
            filter: blur(4px);
  }
}
following is html
```

```html
  <div id="loading">
 <div class="loading-text">
  <span class="loading-text-words">L</span>
  <span class="loading-text-words">O</span>
  <span class="loading-text-words">A</span>
  <span class="loading-text-words">D</span>
  <span class="loading-text-words">I</span>
  <span class="loading-text-words">N</span>
  <span class="loading-text-words">G</span>
 </div></div>
```

Comment: https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the content at the beginning and show the loading stage with something like this:

```
#loading {
    display: block;
}

.content { 
    display: none;
}
```

Then you could set the timeout of how much of the time you want to see the loading phase, then fade out the loader and fade in the content.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("#loading").fadeOut();
    $(".content").fadeIn(); 
}, 3000);
```